# SBS 2011: can't open web-based Sharepoint Designer

Tags: iis, connection, sharepoint-2010, windows-sbs-2011, sharepoint

We installed SBS 2011 (Sharepoint 2010) a couple of years ago and it's running fine. We **never used Sharepoint** features.

Now we wanted to explore Workflow features so I went to `http://sites` and logged in as a Sharepoint administrator (successfully).

My problem is that whenever I need to go into the **web-based Sharepoint Designer**, I get an error. The designer is active on the server, it should be available at `https://sites:987`, but I always get `Connection reset` when I browse to that address.

I even tried momentarily bringing down the Server Firewall to check if it was a firewall problem, but the same thing happens...

A distinctive circumstance of this server is that it is not connected to the Internet(that's a company requirement, I can connect occasionally for updates, but not permanently). I've been told this shouldn't be a problem for what I'm trying to do.

Can you please advise, and help me troubleshoot? Thank you.

Comment: Are any events logged in the Windows Event logs when you try to load the web-based SharePoint designer? If so, please include them in your question.

Comment: Sorry, nothing. I checked these logs: Windows\Application, Windows\Security, Windows\System, Microsoft\Sharepoint_Products\\*, Microsoft\Windows_Small_Business_Server\\*.

Comment: I find it very stranged that nothing is getting logged. There must be something in some IIS log that I don't know of...

Comment: Are any related SharePoint events logged when the server is booted?

Comment: I was able to reboot the server and I can't see anything too suspicious in the Event Logs.

Comment: See if you need to install a patch for SharePoint as directed here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2011/05/24/you-must-manually-run-psconfig-after-installing-sharepoint-2010-patches.aspx

Comment: I am familiar with the need to run `psconfig` after upgrades, and I just checked and my server is fine regarding that.

Comment: Ok, good. You noted this server isn't typically connected to the Internet. Are all of the latest updates installed?

Comment: I connect monthly for updates. I think it has all the updates up to mid-January, and will soon be getting the latest.

Comment: 1) Are any log files modified anywhere in the `C:\Program Files\Windows Small Business Server\Logs` folder structure when you try to access SharePoint Designer? 2) Have you tried accessing the Designer from different workstations/OSes/Browsers?

Comment: *We never used Sharepoint features*... You may also want to consider [repairing or reinstalling SharePoint on SBS2011](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg680310.aspx)

Comment: @Twisty: thanks for your help. I tried 3 different OS's, and several browsers on each. I also tried IE on the server itself, and it still doesn't show anything. The logs you mention don't show anything new when I try to connect.

Comment: I guess I could go reinstalling Sharepoint (I wouldn't need to rebuild any data), but I'm afraid I might break something, it feels risky. This is a live server though it is virtualized so I could snapshot it. But I would prefer if I could avoid the downtime and get some more directed solution (like actually tracing the request through its steps to know where it is breaking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft provides a [helpful guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg680310.aspx) on TechNet for repairing SharePoint Foundation 2010 on Windows Small Business Server 2011.  You can complete the following repair steps without deleting any existing data:

1. [Repair the SharePoint Foundation 2010 Domain Name System](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg680322.aspx)
2. [Repair user access to the internal website](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg680314.aspx)
3. [Repair user access to SharePoint Foundation 2010](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg680334.aspx)

If these repair attempts fail, your next step is to [Recreate your SharePoint Foundation 2010 application and content database](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg680312.aspx).  This step is more invasive but still leaves you with your own data, as noted in the article:

> This topic describes the steps necessary to repair the Windows SBS SharePoint web application and content database. If you experience problems with a different SharePoint Foundation 2010 web application, you can follow the steps in this topic to repair the content database for that application.

---

**This is a lot of work to save content you've never created.**  If I were in your shoes I'd jump right to the end and [Reinstall SharePoint Foundation 2010](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg680325.aspx).  No, you don't walk away knowing exactly what broke your old environment, but you will probably save yourself a lot of time chasing an answer that may never be found anyway.

Comment: This means hours of work, and off work hours, I will try to avoid it. It is a "blind" solution to a problem that I thought was very simple. But if nobody gives any better solution, maybe the problem is not that simple! :-) I will award the points to you at the end of the bounty period if nothing better comes along. Once again, thanks for all your efforts.

Comment: I completely understand and would also search for a direct solution as you are doing. It would be great if you find one, but if not, this is likely what you'll have to do.